Could not find any REST API documentation regarding FCM v1 subscribe to a topic
In the FCM legacy version, I could subscribe to a topic by using REST API by this url and used FCM server key for authentication.
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/{device_token}/rel/topics/{topic}
But as we know in the V1 there will be no Server key auth, instead we have to use bearer token.
Official documentation all about SDK but i don't want to use the SDK.
Thus, is there anyone who could help me to find the the proper implementation of subscribe to a topic using REST API.
